# Has SGA 4½ been typeset in TeX?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology

The title says it all. I've CW'd the question since I'm answering it, as this seemed like the best way to get the news out.

Comment: Congratulations on completing this great service to the algebraic geometry community!  @user111072, I guess that your reaction is a result of ignorance about SGA 4 1/2 and its importance in modern algebraic geometry, which is proved further by your mistakenly attributing it to Grothendieck.  Rest assured, there are plenty who will be very happy to hear about a TeXed version.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes it has. See the links [here](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~dkmiller/). Also [here is the Github repo](https://github.com/dkmiller/sga4.5) if you would like to modify it or propose improvements.

Comment: I heard, anecdotally, that Sophie Morel did this once, for herself.

Comment: You seem to have two versions: sga4.5 and sga4.5-tree. What's the difference?

Comment: The correct link for the links is [this one](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~dkmiller/sga/).

Comment: All links above are dead now. In the Wayback Machine, one can find [old Daniel Miller's webpage](https://web.archive.org/web/20170225055532/http://www.math.cornell.edu/~dkmiller) and his [old github repo](https://web.archive.org/web/20180611012942/https://github.com/dkmiller/sga4.5) (currently deleted). But sadly the Wayback Machine hasn't archived any link with the pdf file (at least I've been unable to find one). (I wanted to contact Miller to ask him about it, but I cannot find any email address online.)

Comment: Good news: [Here](https://github.com/NomiL/sga4.5/)'s a copy of the github repo. [Here](https://matematicas.unex.es/~navarro/res/sga/SGA%204%20%26%20HALF%20-%20Cohomologie%20Etale.pdf)'s a pdf compiled version.